# how to make an app that the buyer can install twice on one device?

Tags: android, iphone, installation

I developed a remote app where the user has to provide an ethernet ID for the target device.

**For users who have two of these devices I would like to give the possibility to install the app twice, one for each device.**

But they should **not have to pay for the second one** (eg just selling the same app with different package-names might not even be accepted by Apple, while on Android it is possible)

Designing the app in such a way that it works with two devices would make it quite complex to use.

**Is there a good workable solution for this for iPhone and/or Android?**

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an iPhone perspective, this wouldn't be possible. Selling the app with different package names is a very poor solution for a number of reasons:

- As you say, it wouldn't be accepted by the App Store (and would probably be eventually removed from the Android Market if it is just a duplicate app).
- You have no control over which version of the app people download, and then need to keep track of this, which is overly complex.
- 2 versions of the app would be acceptable if the user has 2 devices, but what if they have 3? What if they had 10?

To me, this would seem like an issue that would be solved by some sort of severside registration server which links up to some logic within the app in order to determine whether the user has made the necessary payment in order to use the app.

In other words -- and if I am understanding the concept of your app correctly *(more explanation would be needed for a more complete answer)* -- the user goes onto your site (or within the app) and creates an account, registering their Ethernet ID(s) and arranging any payment (or does this via in-app purchase).  You could even charge on a per-device basis and have this built in to the app via in-app purchasing.

So the app itself would be free, but in order to use the app they would need an account which has been registered with you in order to ensure it is only being used by paid users.

Comment: ...thanks, but I do not really understand how a user than cen have two versions of the app on one iPhone/Android ? I understand that I could take care of the used licences/devices - but I need the same app on one phone twice - if possible. - sorry if I didn't make that clear enough in my question. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Yes, I understand that you want to install the same app on a phone twice... but the question is: why?

Instead of having two different apps A and B, why not have one app X which has some logic (querying server or whatever) to decide whether to "become" (i.e. act like) A or B.

There is simply no practical reason (at least none that I can think of) for why you would want to have the same app installed on a device twice...

If you're OK with sharing a little more info about why you need to do that then I would be happy to advise you further.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you trying to build but there are other apps (games & tools) have a client and a server app.

Usually people give the client app away for free, but charge for the server app.

Another way, you could do in-app billing so give the app away for free, but charge for the features in the app to unlock it.
Implement your own registration server that keeps track of registered/licensed devices a user has.
That would you would know that a user has bought the required upgrade that can be used with his/her registration on x number of devices.
Each device the user downloads the app onto and logs into their account.
The app could check check if they have purchased the licence on at least one of their devices, thus unlocking the features.

Not definitive, but those are the two ways I would look into if I were developing such an application

Answer (score 0):

Any iOS app from the App store can already be installed on multiple devices, as many as are logged into to the same iTunes customer account.  The customer only pays once for one to as many installs as they have devices on that same account.